# Solve a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve this trigonometric equation: $3\tan x+5=2$.
This is how I'm trying to solve it:
$$
3\tan x+5=2
\Leftrightarrow \tan x+5=\frac{2}{3}
\Leftrightarrow x+5=0,588+k.\pi
\Leftrightarrow x=-4,412+k.\pi
$$
When I check on photomath it tells me I'm correct however in my math book they say the answer is $-\frac{\pi}{4}+k.\pi$

Comment: $$3\tan x + 5 = 2 \iff \tan x + \frac53 = \frac23$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion probably stems from the fact that $3\tan (x) +5 \neq 3\tan (x+5)$.

The intended answer in your math book corresponds to the equation $3\tan (x) +5 = 2$, while you interpreted the question differently and solved the equation $3\tan (x+5) = 2$ instead.

Parentheses matter!

Comment: Sorry they don't put parenthesis in my book I should have tried with $3\tan (x) +5$. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer was indeed helpful, I'd appreciate it if you mark the answer as accepted and upvote it.

Comment: Sorry I still needed to wait for 2min. because I just uploaded my question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you re-arrange this to show that you have $\tan x = -1$ ? And then take it from there?

Comment: I don't get why $\frac{3\tan x+5}{3}=\frac{2}{3} \Leftrightarrow \tan x+\frac{5}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$ and not $\tan x+5=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: @TomCajot $$\frac{a+b}{c} = \frac ac +\frac bc $$

Comment: Oh, wait are you trying to solve $3 \tan x +5 = 2$ or $3 \tan(x+5)-2$?